# Can a section of the code be interfering with the loop?

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I'm coding a calculator in C that does basic arithmetic and can loop until the user imput a command otherwise. I thought I was getting the hang of loops, but I only put one loop (to start a new operation) and it isn't working. Can a section of the code be interfering with the loop? Is the syntax wrong? The program works fine otherwise.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char reponse;

    int oper;
    float nb1, nb2, resultat;

    do
    {
        printf("Entrez les deux valeurs que vous voulez calculer: \n");
        scanf("%f %f", &nb1, &nb2);

        printf("\nValidez votre op\x82rateur pour effectuer votre cacul\n");
        printf("choisissez \"1\" pour une addition, \"2\" pour une soustraction,\n");
        printf("\"3\" pour une multiplication ou \"4\" pour une division\n");
        scanf(" %d", &oper);

        switch(oper )
        {
            case 1:
                resultat = nb1 + nb2;
                printf("\n%.2f + %.2f = %.2f\n", nb1, nb2, resultat);
                break;
            case 2:
                resultat = nb1 - nb2;
                printf("\n%.2f - %.2f = %.2f\n", nb1, nb2, resultat);
                break;
            case 3: resultat = nb1 * nb2;
                printf("\n%.2f * %.2f = %.2f\n", nb1, nb2, resultat);
                break;
            case 4: resultat = nb1 / nb2;
                printf("\n%.2f / %.2f = %.2f\n", nb1, nb2, resultat);
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nErreur\n");
        }

        printf("\nVoulez-vous continuer \x85 faire des op\x82rations? [o/n]\n");
        scanf(" c%", &reponse);
    } while (reponse == 'o' || reponse == 'O');


    printf("\nMerci au revoir ! Appuyez sur une touche quelconque pour terminer");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `c%` in scanf should instead be `%c`

Comment: No, the `scanf` is getting a \n and not waiting for the user to enter 'o'

Comment: (when I said "no", I meant "no that's not all") - see my answer below

Comment: @iccthedral: aaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhh that's it! thanks. arhg, I'm such a cluts!!!

Comment: @Phil Newbie - there are actually a couple of problems.  As you'll soon find (if you haven't already) both iccthedral and William Morris are correct.  Please be sure to upvote William Morris and "accept" his answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
char reponse[4];

....

scanf("%3s", reponse);
} while (reponse[0] == 'o' || reponse[0] == 'O');
```